# How to inject HttpServletRequest into ContainerRequestFilter with Mockito @InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, jax-rs

I can't copy the exact code here but I will put a sample class that explains the problem I am facing.

```
public XYZ implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext abc){
        //rest of the code below where httpServletRequest is used inside 
    }
}
```

So when I write a write test code using `@InjectMocks`, the `HttpServletRequest` instance is not injected and is null.

Can anyone help me here what I am misssing.

I have even used the following in `@Before` method but still no resolution.

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Comment: If the [code below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51721614/2587435) works for you, and you can't figure out how to make it work for your real code, then you will need to post a [MCVE] the reproduces your problem. The code I posted below is a great example of an MCVE. Beside the missing import statements, everything is self-contained in the example, and you can pretty much copy/paste/run the test. If you can create something similar, it will be easier for use to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can verify that it works fine. See below example, where I mock the `HttpServletRequest` and provide a remote address when `getRemoteAddr()` is called. I use that mocked value to set a property in the `ContainerRequestContext`. I then use `ArgumentCaptor`s to capture the value to test.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class MockitoInjectMocksTest {

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    private ContainerRequestContext requestContext;

    /**
     * With the @InjectMocks annotation, Mockito will
     * inject the filter with the mock HttpServletRequest
     */
    @InjectMocks
    private Filter filter = new Filter();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Handle all the mock creation and injection.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Mock the HttpServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()
        // method to return a dummy IP address.
        Mockito.when(request.getRemoteAddr())
                .thenReturn("122.21.32.233");
    }

    /**
     * See the `Filter` class below. The `filter()` method doesn't
     * do much. It just grabs the remote IP address from the
     * `HttpServletRequest` and uses it to set a property on
     * the `ContainerRequestContext`. This test asserts that
     * the arguments passed to the `setProperty()` method
     * method are the correct arguments. We do that with the
     * help of Mockito's `ArgumentCaptor`,
     */
    @Test
    public void testIpPropertySet() throws Exception {
        // Call the `filter()` method that we are testing,
        // passing in the mock `ContainerRequestContext`.
        // We use a mock so that we can later verify methods
        // on it are called
        filter.filter(requestContext);

        // We create argument captors to capture the args of call to
        // `ContainerRequestContext#setProperty(String, String)`
        ArgumentCaptor<String> propNameArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> propValArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

        // Verify the `ContainerRequestContext#setProperty()`
        // is called. We use the `ArgumentCaptors` to capture
        // the arguments that are passed when `setProperty()`
        // is called.
        Mockito.verify(requestContext)
               .setProperty(propNameArg.capture(), propValArg.capture());

        // Test that the arguments passed in the call to
        // `ContainerRequestContext#setProperty()` are correct.
        assertThat(propNameArg.getValue()).isEqualTo("RemoteAddress");
        assertThat(propValArg.getValue()).isEqualTo("122.21.32.233");
    }

    public static class Filter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Context
        private HttpServletRequest request;

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
            requestContext.setProperty("RemoteAddress", request.getRemoteAddr());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @PaulSamsotha . Thanks for your response. I have a similar Test class code at my end which isnt working. According to you solution , 
request.getRemoteAddress() still get NullPointerException for me and request object is still not injected.

Comment: I am independently testing the class ( which is Filter from your code) and have taken care of all the dependencies. It still throws me nullpointer. I will further look into any missing configurations or dependencies and update this post with a working solution if i find any. if you know this can be done in any other way possible let me know

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot guess what your code looks like. My powers are not that strong. As you can see, my code works fine. For better help, please post a [MCVE] like I suggested in my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720864/how-to-inject-httpservletrequest-into-containerrequestfilter-with-mockito-injec/51721614?noredirect=1#comment90403715_51720864). You don't have to post your complete code. Just take my code and refactor it to make it fail, so it reproduces your problem. Doing so, may also help you narrow down what the problem is,

Comment: I updated the code with a lot of comments, so you can see everything I am doing.

Comment: Thanks for that.i have understood how it is done.I have run you code exactly the same adding few extra changes from my actual code which seems to work but not my project code. figuring out whats wrong. i will update the resolution once i found out.

Comment: The issue was resolved. It was with creating a new object of the class to be tested, in this example Filter class. I did "new Filter()" inside my test method which was not injecting request reference. In your case it was directly done where "@InjectMocks" was created.

I have moved the object creation in "@Before" method and it works now.